# Emails templates in the language of the receiver

Tags: email, message-templates, localisation, language

I am working on a project in Belgium, where they speak French and Dutch. Now I want to send an email in the language of the receiver, using a standard template. Does CiviCRM offer options to support this (other than coding this with smarty if then else)?

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no approach for this on CiviCRM beyond smarty approach. We workaround this by splitting receivers groups by their language preferences and sending their separate mails from templates builded in different languages.

This approach its fine for us. See [this feature request on Mosaico project](https://github.com/voidlabs/mosaico/issues/399) with the aim of facilitating work in this direction.

Also, maybe it would be better to find a language preference filter directly on the CiviMail UI without the need to have to separate the mailing groups by language previously.